# Web Service Provider (CXF/WebSphere) Validates Signed Body, But Not Signed Timestamps in Security Header

Tags: java, timestamp, websphere, cxf, ws-security

I am using Apache CXF 3.0.11, integrated with WebSphere 8.5.5.8, and I have implemented a WebSphere-installed application that provides a Web Service that was developed top-down/WSDL-first. This Web Service uses WS-Security configured through policies in the WSDL.

The Web Service, WebServiceA, runs on an application called AppAlpha. The client, a standalone Java application, is called AppBravo.

The policies are:

1. Include timestamps in the security header.
2. Digitally sign the body as well as the header (which is basically just the timestamps in the security header) with an X.509 digital certificate.

In examining the logs, I can see that...

- AppBravo is signing the body and timestamps.
- AppAlpha recognizes the timestamps in the security header.
- **AppAlpha fails to validate the digital signature on the timestamps -- that is, the actual digest as computed by AppAlpha does not match the expected digest, contained in the request XML.**
- AppAlpha seemingly successfully validates the digital signature on the body -- that is, the actual digest as computed by AppAlpha does match the expected digest, contained in the request XML.

*Does anyone know why the Web Service provider would successfully validate the request message body, but not the timestamps in the message security header?*

WSDL of WebServiceA:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/contract/WebServiceA" xmlns:common="http://common.webservicea.webservice.com" xmlns:x1="http://webservicea.webservice.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" name="WebServiceA" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/contract/WebServiceA">
  <types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://common.webservicea.webservice.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
      <xs:include schemaLocation="WebServiceACommonTypes.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://webservicea.webservice.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="sendDataA">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="theDataA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="sendDataAResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="theResponseA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="msgSendDataARequest">
    <part name="inA" element="x1:sendDataA"/>
  </message>
  <message name="msgSendDataAResponse">
    <part name="outA" element="x1:sendDataAResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="WebServiceAEndpointException">
    <part name="fault" element="common:WebServiceAEndpointFault"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="WebServiceAEndpoint">
    <operation name="sendDataA">
      <input name="msgSendDataARequest" message="tns:msgSendDataARequest"/>
      <output name="msgSendDataAResponse" message="tns:msgSendDataAResponse"/>
      <fault name="WebServiceAEndpointException" message="tns:WebServiceAEndpointException"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="WebServiceAPortBinding" type="tns:WebServiceAEndpoint">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WebServiceABCommonPortBindingPolicy"/>
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="sendDataA">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <input name="msgSendDataARequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WebServiceABCommonPartsPolicy"/>
      </input>
      <output name="msgSendDataAResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WebServiceABCommonPartsPolicy"/>
      </output>
      <fault name="WebServiceAEndpointException">
        <soap:fault name="WebServiceAEndpointException" use="literal"/>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WebServiceABCommonPartsPolicy"/>
      </fault>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="WebServiceA">
    <port name="WebServiceAPort" binding="tns:WebServiceAPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://my.testenvironment.com:9083/AppAlpha/services/WebServiceA"/>
    </port>
  </service>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WebServiceABCommonPortBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:InitiatorToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:X509Token>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:InitiatorToken>
            <sp:RecipientToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
                    <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:X509Token>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:RecipientToken>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
            <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic128/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss11>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WebServiceABCommonPartsPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Body/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
</definitions>
```

Console output from AppBravo, the client of WebServiceA:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_1/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/me/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace_WSDL_20161108/AppBravo/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.14.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Dec 16, 2016 4:12:59 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@db64d237: startup date [Fri Dec 16 16:12:59 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 16, 2016 4:12:59 PM org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext getConfigResources
INFO: Loaded configuration file cxf.xml.
Dec 16, 2016 4:12:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [cxf.xml]
Dec 16, 2016 4:12:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@be48d7d7: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,{http://www.example.com/contract/WebServiceA}WebServiceAPort.jaxws-client.proxyFactory,{http://www.example.com/contract/WebServiceA}WebServiceAPort.jaxws-client]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 16, 2016 4:13:00 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.example.com/contract/WebServiceA}WebServiceA from WSDL: file:/C:/Users/me/IBM/rationalsdp/workspace_WSDL_20161108/TempCXFCodeGenProject/wsdl/WebServiceA.wsdl
Dec 16, 2016 4:13:00 PM org.apache.cxf.services.WebServiceA.WebServiceAPort.WebServiceAEndpoint null
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: http://my.testenvironment.com:9083/AppAlpha/services/WebServiceA
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=[""]}
Payload: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-4b24dbaf-201c-41c1-8dc7-53f234b3a849"><wsu:Created>2016-12-16T21:13:00.846Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2016-12-16T21:18:00.846Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-fd064e65-9b93-48cd-a56f-041e4d27bb8b">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-3914e870-57e7-4fe1-8b75-52bed65c05f6"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soapenc soapenv xsd xsi"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod><ds:Reference URI="#TS-4b24dbaf-201c-41c1-8dc7-53f234b3a849"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>uLm/Y2FEfFcXfp8W6kfQO86bJ9Y=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#_03eba575-563f-438d-9701-b5a50b8dabe0"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soapenc xsd xsi"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>kQjZ5433MyDvXEcmze8the0EMd8=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>akjjBgGVeeNKAzwmofjOXQo59p3wiHxBfFQPXUdZ2Zo/WbZdnKGzpW1Vg9L+JCpofUAPn0g97OPnE0EII8aMSgOuFEU9VdtjU0Dwn1GPLUSVCWub74qe1r7ojr841VXP5YtSb2+WKBiFLgG74yqnnpneKBA8j+KAnYxo+NvYdhtgrCwoNTZBFie1GqEBsyUpCqsJIVZfydTNRGyApSNbTOv0PnwV5ZGFIoVy+7ZPHBsi6kvqkErCZvZ3uztd4jpPPyE0GousCgvEilkMQSm/BaVzXZDyyTtWHesGMR9l6172B4nJ4KTUwhfLy8rU6hjFLletum+Ys9egdD3LWbWguw==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-8d80ebc9-a6de-4498-b8e3-326eb506fee3"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STR-2219d15b-208c-42b0-9721-ab3efbd641b7"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-fd064e65-9b93-48cd-a56f-041e4d27bb8b" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></wsse:Reference></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="_03eba575-563f-438d-9701-b5a50b8dabe0"><sendDataA xmlns="http://webservicea.webservice.com" xmlns:ns2="http://common.webservicea.webservice.com"><theDataA>Test invocation of Web Service A</theDataA></sendDataA></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
Dec 16, 2016 4:13:02 PM org.apache.cxf.services.WebServiceA.WebServiceAPort.WebServiceAEndpoint null
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {connection=[Close], Content-Language=[en-US], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], Date=[Fri, 16 Dec 2016 21:13:02 GMT], transfer-encoding=[chunked], X-Powered-By=[Servlet/3.0]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://ws.apache.org/wss4j">ns1:SecurityError</faultcode><faultstring>A security error was encountered when verifying the message</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
Dec 16, 2016 4:13:02 PM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor handleMessageInternal
WARNING: The request is a SOAP Fault, but it is not secured
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: A security error was encountered when verifying the message
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.sendDataA(Unknown Source)
    at com.ws.impl.WebServiceAClientStandalone.sendDataA(WebServiceAClientStandalone.java:35)
    at com.ws.impl.WebServiceAClientStandalone.main(WebServiceAClientStandalone.java:29)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was encountered when verifying the message
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
```

Here are excerpts of AppAlpha's log file:

```
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod verify JCA Algorithm: SHA1withRSA
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod verify Signature Bytes length: 256
...
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.DigesterOutputStream write <wsu:Timestamp...
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate Expected digest: uLm/Y2FEfFcXfp8W6kfQO86bJ9Y=
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate Actual digest: ONplUDjf+u6NMCXv7QuuR38YBrQ=
org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature validate Reference[#TS-4b24dbaf-201c-41c1-8dc7-53f234b3a849] is valid: false
...
DigesterOutpu 1 org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.DigesterOutputStream write Pre-digested input:
DigesterOutpu 1 org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.DigesterOutputStream write <soapenv:Body...
DOMReference  1 org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate Expected digest: kQjZ5433MyDvXEcmze8the0EMd8=
DOMReference  1 org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference validate     Actual digest: kQjZ5433MyDvXEcmze8the0EMd8=
SignatureProc 1 org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor verifyXMLSignature Reference #_03eba575-563f-438d-9701-b5a50b8dabe0 check: true
```

Comment: Just an impression, may be client and server are understanding and applying the policy in a different way. cxf version? java version? xml parsers?  To delimit the problem you could run the client from the websphere itself

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just created a servlet which invokes WebServiceA, and the same issue shows up in the server log -- the digitally signed message body validates, but the digitally signed message header timestamps don't.

Comment: When I remove the sp:IncludeTimestamp element from WebServiceABCommonPortBindingPolicy, the Web Service fully passes validation, so the issue indeed seems to lie in the validation of those timestamps. Unfortunately one of the application requirements is to include digitally signed timestamps in the security header.

Comment: Could you generate the SOAP request with a tool like SoapUI? Depending whether the error. Depending on whether the error is still present or not, you can determine if the error is on the server or on the client

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a rookie at setting up security policies with SoapUI. SoapUI doesn't seem to have the capability to read a policy straight from the WSDL, so I'm concerned that I will mis-configure the policy in SoapUI and introduce yet another variable in diagnosing the problem. I'll give this idea a try though. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm still working on getting SoapUI to send the message to the provider, but for grins, I tried removing only the sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody element from WebServiceABCommonPortBindingPolicy, and then tried having AppBravo (running on WebSphere) invoke the service on AppAlpha (also running on WebSphere). The Web Service behaves as before -- the provider validates the digitally signed body, but fails to validate the digitally signed timestamp.

Comment: I am having difficulty configuring SoapUI to match the security policy that is described in the WSDL.

Comment: To simplify, I suggest to import WSDL in SoapUI without policy and configure signature + timestamp using the GUI. You only need to know whether the timestamp generated by a well-known application is accepted or not. I bet for an issue with the server. In this case a workaround could be implement the signature validation yourself using WSS4J

Comment: Got SoapUI to invoke the Web Service. Provider successfully validates both body and timestamp! (It fails on a later step -- "Layout does not match the requirements" -- but I'll worry about that later.)

In comparing a request from the WebSphere/CXF client and a request from SoapUI, we found discrepancies in date formats in the timestamps.

From WebSphere/CXF client (for which TS validation fails): 2016-12-29T18:03:17.023Z

From SoapUI (for which TS validation succeeds): 2016-12-29T18:03:17:02Z

Now it's time to figure out how to get CXF to change the date format of timestamps.

Comment: Interestingly, in SoapUI, if I choose "Add WS-Timestamp", the timestamp's date format matches that of the WebSphere/CXF client's request. If instead in SoapUI, as we've been doing, we add (1) a Timestamp WSS entry and (2) a Signature entry, the timestamp's date format is what I had described in my previous comment.

Comment: The "Layout does not match the requirements" error in the request from SoapUI is because SoapUI puts the timestamp just before the closing tag of the wsse:Security element. When I manually move the timestamp to just after the opening tag of the wsse:Security element, the Web Service provider returns a successful response. Next Step for SoapUI: Figure out how to put the timestamp in the "proper" place in the request message. Next Step for WebSphere/CXF: Figure out how to change the date format of the timestamp. (WebSphere/CXF already puts the timestamp in the "proper" place.)

Comment: I solved SoapUI's last problem -- timestamp location in the security header -- by changing the WSDL's layout policy from Strict to Lax. Still working on the timestamp issue with the WebSphere/CXF-based client application.

Comment: Then, the final problem is a datetime format issue. But `2016-12-29T18:03:17.023Z` should be accepted. See http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp. May be it dislikes the milliseconds, but it should not. The server log file is still confuse, if the datetime is not valid, the error code should not be about not matching digests

Comment: Hmm... it might not be a date format issue. I did notice one more possibly significant difference between SoapUI request XML and WebSphere/CXF request XML. In SoapUI request XML, the timestamp's ds:Reference's ds:Transform element has an ec:InclusiveNamespaces sub-element (with a PrefixList attribute set to "wsse soapenv web"). In the WebSphere/CXF request XML, the timestamp's ds:Reference's ds:Transform element does not have an ec:InclusiveNamespaces sub-element. Might this be a reason why the WebSphere/CXF client application's digitally signed timestamp isn't being validated by the provider?